# wrap images in a div

Tags: html, css

I'm using the following CSS to display images side by side:

```
#gallery {
    background-color: #444;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 520px;
}
#gallery ul { list-style: none; }
#gallery ul li { display: inline; }
#gallery ul img {
    border: 5px solid #3e3e3e;
    border-width: 5px 5px 20px;
}
#gallery ul a:hover img {
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    border-width: 5px 5px 20px;
    color: #fff;
}
#gallery ul a:hover { color: #fff; }
```

html code for above css is:

```
<div id="gallery">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="photos/image1.jpg" title="">
                <img src="photos/thumb_image1.jpg"/>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="photos/image2.jpg" title="">
                <img src="photos/thumb_image2.jpg">
            </a>
        </li>
</div>
```

All works fine, but there might be cases when I will be displaying 20 to 30 images which makes the page very long.  Is there a way to add all this in side something so that the whole page doesnt become big and a scroll bar is added around the container that contains all the images?

Comment: hard to tell from your answer whether you want a scrollbar or don't want a scrollbar?

Comment: The only html element that comes built-in with a scrollbar is textarea. you'll need to find plugins to get that done. Look at javascript frameworks such as JQuery or Mootools

Comment: gAMBOOKa, that is patently false. <DIV> comes built in with a scrollbar. As I note in my answer, just turn the overflow style param to "auto" and the scrollbars will automagically appear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure why you don't want your page to become "long" but you can give the div a specific height and set its overflow to auto, so that the div scrolls while the page remains "short".

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't do it. Just let the page be long and make sure you put the interesting stuff at the top. My browser has a scrollbar and I prefer to use it.
2. If you must... [this](http://www.brunildo.org/test/iframe_h100_hea_foo_abs_6.html) is acceptable.